# Using fundamental matrix to solve inhomogenous IVP

Tags: matrices, ordinary-differential-equations

How can I use the fact that $$ W(x,x_0) = \dfrac{1}{3}
\begin{bmatrix}
       x^2x_0^{-2} + 2x^{-1}x_0&x^2x_0^{-1} - x^{-1}x_0^2 \\
        2xx_0^{-2} - 2x^{-2}x_0 & 2xx_0^{-1} + x^{-2}x_0^2
     \end{bmatrix}
$$

is a fundamental matrix for $$ A(x) = \begin{bmatrix}
       0&1 \\
        2x^{-2} & 0
     \end{bmatrix}
$$
 to solve $x^2y''(x) - 2y(x) = 1 $, $y(x_0) = y_0$, $y'(x_0) = v_0, x>0$

I change it to $y'' - \dfrac{2}{x^2}y = \dfrac{1}{x^2}$, but not sure where to go